# componentWillReceiveProps doesn't re-render the component

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

This is the code of my child component (SecondOrder). I'm trying to draw a donut using d3js and reactjs. The componentWillReceiveProps should re-render the component on getting new props and set the states mentioned in it, right? But it doesn't work properly here. It does triggered but the states are still null or undefined and I'm getting an error when I'm trying to loop over `this.state.selectedNode.connections` because it's still undefined. The weird thing is that the if is also not working `if(this.state.selectedNode !== 'undefined')`! I added the console.log line and it prints to the console only once (meaning the component hasn't re-rendered I guess) when the this.state.selectedNode is undefined! Where is the problem?

```
export default class SecondOrder extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            nodes: [],
            selectedNode: null,
        };
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
        if (newProps.selectedNode !== this.props.selectedNode){
            this.setState({selectedNode:newProps.selectedNode})
        }

        if (newProps.nodes.length !== this.props.nodes.length){
            this.setState({nodes:newProps.nodes})
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var width = 1000;
        var height = 500;
        var fullAngle = 2 * Math.PI;

        var svgContainer = select(".container")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .style("border", "1px solid");

        var secondOrderList = [];
        if(this.state.selectedNode !== 'undefined'){
            console.log("************* ")
            this.state.selectedNode.connections.forEach(target => {
                console.log("target", target)
            });
        }

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="donut" ref={(donut) => { this.donut = donut; }} />
            </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just do `if(this.state.selectedNode){`.

Comment: Condition `if(this.state.selectedNode !== 'undefined'){` will always evaluate to `true` because `selectedNode` is `null`.

Comment: `if(this.state.selectedNode !== 'undefined')` -- did you mean `if(typeof this.state.selectedNode !== 'undefined')`?

Comment: @Prakashsharma thanks, that fixed the weird behaviour of if.  But the re-render issue is still there. componentWillReceiveProps is not re-rendering the component!

Comment: @Nick that is fixed thanks to Prakash sharma 's comment. But the re-rendering of the component is still an issue. componentWillReceiveProps doesn't work properly :/

Comment: @Birish How do you know it is not rerendering? I don't see any `console.log` inside `render` function.

Comment: @Prakashsharma because the states are not updated. Also, the code inside componentDidMount() should print on the console. I added a test console.log() in the render function as well, but it only prints once in the console.

Comment: @Birish That's the mistake. `componentDidMount` is called only once in the entire lifetime of the component. It is not called on every rerender of the component.

Comment: @Prakashsharma So how can I force that to happen? The problem is that I need to write the d3js code inside componentDidMount, where else I can add it?!

Comment: @Birish Use `componentDidUpdate` method instead.

Comment: @Prakashsharma thanks! "Gleb Kost"  just said the same in the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentDidMount` is called only once, on initial render. At that time your state is the following:

```
this.state = {
    nodes: [],
    selectedNode: null,
};
```

Than you get new props and state, probably, gets updated, but there's no method to respond to the updates (at least it's not present in the provided code snippet).

componentDidUpdate can do the trick

Comment: So how can I force that to happen? The problem is that I need to write the d3js code inside componentDidMount, where else I can add it?!